# React useState setter method doesn't refresh correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

`useState` hook doesn't trigger a render as I expect.

#### I expect a new matrix to be created and for the board to return to the original state which has no checked boards/squares.

I'm working on this [Repo](https://github.com/PrimeTimeTran/ts-algo-visualizer).

[Demo App](https://starlit-malabi-009873.netlify.app/)

1. Click any node and watch the breath first search action do its magic.
2. Press "r" and see how the component rerenders but keeps its stale matrix.

#### I use two  [functions to generate](https://github.com/PrimeTimeTran/ts-algo-visualizer/blob/2f64ac2988a134070c7c3b59ea5d45b953c8957c/src/components/Game.tsx#L29) a matrix.

```js
function createNode(rc: string, i: number, j: number) {
  const cur: node = {
    row: i,
    col: j,
    id: rc,
    inRoute: false,
    checked: false,
    distance: Infinity,
    end: rc === FINISH_NODE,
    start: rc === START_NODE,
  };
  return cur
}

function getBoard() {
  console.log('New board')
  var board: node[][] = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
    board[i] = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
      const rc = `${i},${j}`
      const cur = createNode(rc, i, j)
      board[i][j] = cur;
    }
  }
  return board;
}
```

#### I use [this function](https://github.com/PrimeTimeTran/ts-algo-visualizer/blob/2f64ac2988a134070c7c3b59ea5d45b953c8957c/src/components/Game.tsx#L43), `getBoard()` to generate the original matrix

```js
const matrix = getBoard()
const [board, setBoard] = useState(matrix)
```

#### I define a [handler that fires](https://github.com/PrimeTimeTran/ts-algo-visualizer/blob/2f64ac2988a134070c7c3b59ea5d45b953c8957c/src/components/Game.tsx#L49) when the user presses "r" for a refresh.

This calls `setBoard` which fires the function which produces the matrix from scratch.

```js
const onRefresh = (event: { key: string }) => {
  setBoard(getBoard())
  setFinishNode(FINISH_NODE)
};
```

I do see the `console.log('New board')` fire when r is pressed though which is confusing.

Your help is appreciated in advance~!

Thanks~!

Comment: Can you edit your post to include all the relavent code you are working with and have an issue using as part of a [mcve]? We shouldn't need to go spelunking in your repo to find potential issues.

Comment: So what is the issue with `setBoard(getBoard())`? I don't see any reason it wouldn't work and update the `board` state to the returned value from `getBoard`. I do see that a bunch of other functions in the `Game` component are directly mutating the `board` state.

Comment: @DrewReese yessir I agree. However, the matrix squares don't return to their original unchecked states/colors. I have to refresh the entire page to get the matrix to return to it's original state currently.

Comment: How do you know they aren't? What verification proves they didn't?

Comment: I get your point. I have an infinite loop. Thanks